# Apply CodeMirror to a ng-model-bound textarea

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, codemirror, ui-codemirror

I am coding a very very basic playground. For some reason, I need to embed the html panel inside an AngularJS app.

In [this version](https://jsbin.com/mojegof/3/edit?html,js,output), I put a JQuery change listener to the CSS panel, and applied CodeMirror to the textarea. And it worked.

I felt uncomfortable about having a JQuery event listener inside an AngularJS app, so I decided to bind the CSS panel to the AngularJS app, and made [this version](https://jsbin.com/genegu/4/edit?html,js,output). But now, the problem is the CodeMirror code (that I comment below) does not work anymore:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    HTML:<br>
    <textarea rows=10 cols=40 ng-model="area1">html body area</textarea>
    <br>CSS:<br>
    <textarea id="css" rows=10 cols=40 ng-model="css"></textarea>
  </div>
  Output:
  <section id="output">
    <iframe></iframe>
  </section>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.area1 = "<body>default</body>";  
    $scope.$watch('area1', function (json) {
      render();
    }, true);

    $scope.css="body {color: red}";
    $scope.$watch('css', function (json) {
      // CodeMirror does not work anymore
      // var cm_opt = { mode: 'css', gutter: true, lineNumbers: false };
      // var css_box = document.getElementById("css");
      // var css_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(css_box, cm_opt);
      render();
    }, true);

    function render () {
      var source = "<html><head><style>" + $scope.css + "</style></head>" + 
                   $scope.area1 +"</html>";

      var iframe = document.querySelector('#output iframe'),
          iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;

      iframe_doc.open();
      iframe_doc.write(source);
      iframe_doc.close();
    }
 });
```

Does anyone know how to make CodeMirror work here?

Additionally, is it really a bad idea to use JQuery event listeners inside an AngularJS app? What's the best structure to code this playground that uses AngularJS + CodeMirror?

**Edit 1:** I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/n4T2bkVNQgs), then I made a [codeMirror directive](https://jsbin.com/genegu/5/edit?html,js,output), it does not work well. DevTools shows me an error `TypeError: textarea.getAttribute is not a function` at `CodeMirror.fromTextArea(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Here` I added Demo For Code mirror in angularjs. I hope it will help you...

[Here Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ywwLifFlvbjaYvMhb03I?p=preview)

Comment: Indeed, I should use `ui-codemirror`. For the record, here is a [working version](https://jsbin.com/yiviwol/8/edit?html,js,output), and a related question: [Use 2 ui-codemirrors in 1 controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498554/use-2-ui-codemirrors-in-1-controller)

Answer (score 2):

*Response to solve the 2nd attempt of OP*

In the directive's `link` function you are using the `elem` param as a pure HTML element (which is expected by codemirror), but angular provides it as a JQLite wrapped element - so basically you just need to get the HTML element from it and provide **it** to codemirror, then it will work:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(elm[0], cm_opt);
```

(note `elem[0]` instead of `elem`)

In AngularJS it is not a bad practice to use directives to wrap JQuery-based logic to make components that rely on other technologies like code-mirror. In some cases you might do this yourself, but can also use already-built third party libraries as mentioned in the other answers.

Whatever you do, make sure you encapsulate non-angular logic well, by making use of directives and services.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, `var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(elm[0], cm_opt);` does works, and I will use `ui-codemirror`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[UI.Codemirror directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror)