# Use 2 ui-codemirrors in 1 controller

Tags: angularjs, iframe, angular-ui, codemirror, ui-codemirror

I am coding a very very basic playground by using `AngularJS` and `ui-codemirror`. Here is the code ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yiviwol/8/edit?html,js,output)).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <script src="https://codemirror.net/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>
    <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
    <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
    <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/css/css.js"></script>
    <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/clike/clike.js"></script>
    <script src="https://codemirror.net/mode/php/php.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="codeCtrl">
        HTML:<br>
        <textarea ui-codemirror ng-model="html"></textarea>
        <br>CSS:<br>
        <textarea ui-codemirror ng-model="css"></textarea>
      </div>
      Output:
      <section id="output">
        <iframe></iframe>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui']);

myApp.value('ui.config', {
  codemirror: {
    mode: 'text/x-php',
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
  }
});

function codeCtrl($scope, codeService) {
  $scope.html = '<body>default</body>';
  $scope.css = "body {color: red}";

  $scope.$watch('html', function () { codeService.render($scope.html, $scope.css); }, true);
  $scope.$watch('css', function () { codeService.render($scope.html, $scope.css); }, true);
}

myApp.service('codeService', function () {
  this.render = function (html, css) {
    source = "<html><head><style>" + css + "</style></head>" + html +"</html>";

    var iframe = document.querySelector('#output iframe'),
        iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;

    iframe_doc.open();
    iframe_doc.write(source);
    iframe_doc.close();
  }
})
```

The above code works, but the problem is it applies one same `ui.config` to 2 `ui-codemirror`. Does anyone know how to apply mode `html` to the first `ui-codemirror` and mode `css` to the second `ui-codemirror`?

Additionally, how could I set the height (or `rows`) and width (or `cols`) of a `ui-codemirror`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
function codeCtrl($scope, codeService) {

  $scope.editorOptions1 = {mode: 'text/html',
    lineNumbers: false,
    matchBrackets: true};

  $scope.editorOptions2 = {mode: 'text/css',
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true};

  $scope.html = '<body>default</body>';
  $scope.css = "body {color: red}";

  $scope.$watch('html', function () { codeService.render($scope.html, $scope.css); }, true);
  $scope.$watch('css', function () { codeService.render($scope.html, $scope.css); }, true);
}
```

Html :

```
<div ng-controller="codeCtrl">
        HTML:<br>
        <textarea ui-codemirror="editorOptions1" ng-model="html"></textarea>
        <br>CSS:<br>
        <textarea ui-codemirror="editorOptions2" ng-model="css"></textarea>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, for the record, here is the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pelaruhexu/2/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing with two separate text areas that have rather different roles (or imagine if they were more), it makes sense to define separate directives for them, each one accepting a different config object. I've created a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tawudobono/edit?html,js,output) which shows one possible approach, via directive factory that can be used to generated different "mirrors".

```
angular.module('codeMirrorApp')
  .factory('CodeMirrorFactory', ['$parse',
    function($parse) {
      return {
        createDirective: function(config) {
          var configString = JSON.stringify(config);
          return {
            scope: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<textarea ui-codemirror=' + configString + ' ng-model="content"></textarea>',
            controller: ['$scope', '$attrs', function($scope, $attrs) {
              var handler = $parse($attrs.handler);

              $scope.$watch('content', function(value) {
                handler($scope, { content: value });
              });
            }]
          };
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

I'm intentionally using handlers provided by the parent controller instead of bindings to the parent scope as this makes things look more understandable even while looking at the HTML markup.

The controller:

```
angular.module('codeMirrorApp')
  .controller('MirrorsController', ['RenderMirrors',
    function(RenderMirrors) {
      var ctrl = this,
          html,
          css;

      ctrl.handleHtml = function(htmlString) {
        html = htmlString;
        RenderMirrors.render(html, css);
      };

      ctrl.handleCss = function(cssString) {
        css = cssString;
        RenderMirrors.render(html, css);
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="codeMirrorApp">
  <div ng-controller="MirrorsController as ctrl">
    HTML:<br>
    <html-code-mirror handler="ctrl.handleHtml(content)"></html-code-mirror>
    <br>CSS:<br>
    <css-code-mirror handler="ctrl.handleCss(content)"></css-code-mirror>
  </div>
  Output:
  <section id="output">
    <iframe></iframe>
  </section>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.